# Perl Command Line Interpreter crashing on exit

Tags: perl, user-interface, crash, interpreter, tkx

I have an issue where exiting a Perl `Tkx` script causes the Perl Command Line Interpreter to crash.

Ex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tkx;

my $mw     = Tkx::widget->new('.');
my $button = $mw->new_ttk__button(-text => "Hello", -command => \&main);

Tkx::pack($button);

Tkx::MainLoop;

sub main {
    print "TESTING\n";
    exit 0;
}
```

This code generates the following output:

[image: Main Window]

Clicking the "Hello" button invokes the `main()` subroutine which prints "TESTING" and then attempts to exit and crashes the Command Line Interpreter:

[image: Error Message]

This only seems to be happening with `Tkx` scripts and will only crash if the program has already entered the `MainLoop` before calling `exit`.   Does anyone know what is going on here?

---

Perl version information:

[image: Perl Version]

Comment: What about adding `$mw->g_destroy` before `exit`?

Comment: I guess that works, but still why would it be crashing the interpreter if you don't manually destroy the window first?  Perl is supposed to be able to clean up and destroy the window itself.

Comment: During global destruction, objects might be destroyed in any order.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting to know.  What's strange is this seemed to be working before I switched from 64 bit Perl to 32 bit to try and solve a different issue.  I think this showed up after I switched to 32 bit Perl.  I will try switching back to the 64 bit version and see if it works without using `g_destroy` and I will let you know what I find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this issue started when I switched from 64 bit Perl to 32 bit Perl.  Switching back to the 64 bit version of Perl solved the problem.

It is worth noting that choroba's solution to destroy the main window using `g_destroy` before exiting did solve the problem even when running the 32 bit version of Perl.  Also it is probably better practice to manually destroy your window before exiting even if Perl can clean it up on its own... you never know what version of Perl someone else trying to run your script might have!